# Prevent page loading in QWebView after click on flash player

Tags: html, qt, flash

I have a `QWebView` and a `flash` `player` which, on context menu click, can redirect user to another pages — some of context menu actions are links. So, is here any solutions to prevent `QWebView` of redirecting after click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reimplementing of `QWebPage::acceptNavigationRequest` helps me.